# Access Windows' shared network from Mac

Tags: network, sharing, virtualization, parallels-desktop

I try to use Windows 10 via `Parallels Desktop` in my Mac. Here is the sharing setting of `Parallels Desktop`:

[image]

[image]

In the navigation bar of File Explorer of Windows, we can see and enter a network `TIECHENG9FDC`:

[image]

In Mac, I can see `tiecheng9fdc` under `Shared` in the navigation bar of Finder. However, I cannot access it:

[image]

[image]

Does anyone know what should I do to access `tiecheng9fdc` of Windows from Mac?